# Div Class Ignore Div ID When i put a float:left in my css page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a picture gallery, but it doesn't work cause of one thing, and I really don't understand why it doesn't work :

There is my CSS :

```
#maincontent {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 960px;
  border: solid 10px #4d8720;
  background: #111111;
}

div.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 180px;
  float: left;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 3px solid #FF0000;
}
```

My PHP file :

```
<div id="maincontent">

<?php if (is_numeric($newtarget)) { ?> 
      <div class="gallery">

          <a target="_blank" href="/Projet/images/<?php echo $user['id']  ?>.jpg">
          <img src="/Projet/images/<?php echo $user['id']  ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $user['title'] ?> " width="500" height="400">
          </a>

          <div class="desc"><?php echo $user['description'] ?>  <br />Autor : "<?php echo $donnees['pseudo']; ?>"</div>

      </div>
<?php } else { ?>
      <div class="gallery">

        <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $user['FileName']  ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $user['FileName']  ?>" alt="<?php echo $user['title'] ?> " width="500" height="400">
        </a>

        <div class="desc"><?php echo $user['description'] ?>  <br />Autor : "<?php echo $donnees['pseudo']; ?>"</div>

      </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

So, When i delete the float:left; in my CSS file (div.gallery) it work but don't display the gallery with aligned picture, it displays them 1per1 but when I put the float it work but it ignores my div id I don't understand what is wrong:   `<div id ="maincontent">`

Comment: It might be about clearing floats https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ (once you read it, add overflow:hidden to #maincontent to understand what it involves)

Comment: @G-Cyr , Damn thank you so much it litteraly unlocked me <3 thanks for helping a beginner in CSS. Tons of kiss from Paris haha <3

Comment: You should put the <div class="gallery"> only once and wrap the if statement with it.

Comment: @RicardoNuñez yep i did it thanks, i just was trying different way to put my <div class="gallery"> because i was hardstuck. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, i'm closed to Paris , funny to meet here . css-tricks have a few tutorials/reminder quiet usefull and easy to share.